# fade out of scenes

Tags: camera, marker

I was wondering is there a way to phase in my next camera scene? Meaning, in blender you have markers that allow you to hop from one camera to the next, but instead of instantaneously I would like to phase it in, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Do you mean a 2D cross-fade? That would be a job for video editing (Blender VSE)

Comment: Yes, I'll give that a try, and try to figure it out. Thank you.